# asp.net calling javascript / jquery whilst passing div components in repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asprepeater

I'm trying to pass two div components to a javascript function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function clicked(item, txtMessage) {
             txtMessage.text((parseInt(txtMessage.text()) + parseInt(100)));
         }
</script>

<asp:Repeater ID="repGridView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepGridView_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="false">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <div>
                     <div id="txtMessage" >5000</div>
                     <button type="button" onclick="clicked(this, 'txtMessage');">ADD NOW</button>
                 </div>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: You don't need this bit: `$(`. Also, there's no harm on checking the console for errors.

Comment: there's 2 lines of code here.  i'd normally complain about lack of an error message too but it's pretty clear what the issue is if you take 5 seconds to read the code.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Jquery or vanilla JavaScript? It's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

as this is a repeater usage of id would not work for you as id must be unique. If this is your actual layout try something as below or find the text relative the sender (item in your function) object.

```
function clicked(item) {
         var $txtMessage = $(item).prev(); 

         $txtMessage.text((parseInt($txtMessage.text()) + parseInt(100)));
}
```

change the function call as below;

```
onclick="clicked(this);"
```

Comment: good call on the repeater/id issue

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to the function as the 2nd param but then acting like it is a jQuery object.  Try this.

```
function clicked(item, txtMessage) {
         $txtMessage = $('#' + txtMessage); // convert the string to a jquery object representing the DOM element with the ID passed in the txtMessage parameter
         $txtMessage.text((parseInt($txtMessage.text()) + parseInt(100)));
}
```

Comment: Are they using Jquery? there is no Jquery tag.

Comment: it's in the title of the question